# Notification Activate

Tags: android, notifications

i want to call the activity when user pull down the notification and click on that notification...how can i do that?

here's my code :

```
public class SetReminder extends AppCompatActivity {
int notifyID = 1088;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_notification);

    TextView helpsubtitle = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.subtitle_help);
    Typeface typeface = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "beyond_the_mountains.ttf");
    helpsubtitle.setTypeface(typeface);

    NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =

            new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.diamond)
                    .setContentTitle("Crystallise")
                    .setContentText("making your thoughts crystal clear");
    NotificationManager mNotificationManager =
            (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    mNotificationManager.notify(notifyID, mBuilder.build());
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you need to create an `Intent` which specifies the activity you want to launch when the user clicks on the notification. Assuming you want `MainActivity` to open when the notification is clicked, use the following code to create the intent:
`Intent intent = new Intent(SetReminder.this, MainActivity.class);`

Then, you must specify a `PendingIntent`, which is a token you give to the `NotificationManager`, or any other foreign application in general:

```
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(
        context, 0,
        intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT
);
```

Apply this `pendingIntent` to your notification using `.setContentIntent(pendingIntent)`.

Your final code should look like this:

```
public class SetReminder extends AppCompatActivity {
    int notifyID = 1088;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_notification);

        TextView helpsubtitle = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.subtitle_help);
        Typeface typeface = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "beyond_the_mountains.ttf");
helpsubtitle.setTypeface(typeface);

        Intent intent = new Intent(SetReminder.this, MainActivity.class);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(
                context, 0,
                intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT
        );
        NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.diamond)
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                .setContentTitle("Crystallise")
                .setContentText("making your thoughts crystal clear");
        NotificationManager mNotificationManager =
            (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        mNotificationManager.notify(notifyID, mBuilder.build());
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to pass the context.
Since you're already in an activity, and you're creating the notification from an activity itself, you should replace `context` with `SetReminder.this`